# mongodb kubernetes: how to spin up a read-only replica?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, database-replication, readonly

So I want to have one kubernetes cluster where the mongodb is configured with replicas and I want to have ANOTHER kubernetes cluster where I want a local mongodb which is a read-only replica of the former cluster. There are mongodb samples on the kubernetes schemas to use to create a mongodb replica set - ie to achieve the former. But how do I achieve the latter, what kind of kubernetes yamls/schema do I use for that, how do I specify the 'read only" nature in the schema etc.. ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, provide scenario and your configuration. You want to have 2 clusters with mongoDB. Does those clusters will have access to the same database or there should be 2 different? Elaborate what do you mean by `read-only replica of the former cluster`.

Comment: Hi, Yes the two clusters need the same database. One cluster will be the main cluster where data gets added/modified etc.. The other cluster just needs a local read-only copy of the data, it does not want to / should not be able to modify anything - I guess which is what mongodb calls a read-only-replica ?